# Filter and reduce given jQuery collection of DOM elements so that elements that are children of other elements in the collection are removed from it

Tags: javascript, jquery, filter

I have a collection of DOM elements that was created using RegEx on nodes to look for a particular keyword. This collection contains all sorts of HTML elements.

How can such a collection be narrowed down to contain only top level elements?

-- Essentially, given collection_A create a collection_B that does not contain elements that may be children of other elements in the collection.

For example:

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div class="div_1"> no key here </div>
<div class="div_2"> no key here </div>
<div class="div_3"> contains {key}
  <div class="div_a"> no key here </div>
  <div class="div_b"> contains {key} </div>
  <div class="div_c"> no key here </div>
  <div class="div_d"> contains {key}
    <div class="div_e"> contains {key} </div>
    <div class="div_f"> no key here </div>
    <div class="div_g"> contains {key} </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="div_4"> no key here </div>
<div class="div_5"> no key here </div>
<div class="div_6"> contains {key} </div>
<div class="div_7"> no key here
  <div class="div_h"> no key here </div>
  <div class="div_i"> contains {key} </div>
  <div class="div_j"> no key here </div>
  <div class="div_k"> contains {key}
    <div class="div_l"> contains {key} </div>
    <div class="div_m"> no key here </div>
    <div class="div_n"> contains {key} </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

So the jQuery collection now contains the following DOM elements:

```
[".div_3", ".div_b", ".div_d", ".div_e", ".div_g", ".div_6", ".div_i", ".div_k", ".div_l", ".div_n"]
```

How can I filter this collection to become the following: ?

```
[".div_3", ".div_6", ".div_i", ".div_k"]
```

Thanks in advance guys for any help here !

---

@mplungjan - Long story:
The gist of it is that a collection of Regexs is used to collect all text nodes that contain a particular moustache style key for example "{{this_is_a_key}}". Then "non-text-node" parents of these text nodes are added to a collection.

DOM elements in this jQuery collection (are converted into HTML strings and) need to be processed to replace the keys in PHP on the server via an AJAX request, however only the top-level elements need to be processed because children are already being processed within the top-level elements.

Comment: Please add your jQuery code to the snippet I made

Comment: @mplungjan , the jQuery code is very complex and has a lot of non-essential code and logic and adding that here would not make the question any good or simpler ... I believe. please see update at the bottom of the question :)

Comment: Do you have an array of IDs, or a jquery collection?

Comment: Its a jQuery collection. It can sometimes be rather large collection and contains many different HTML tags, classes, ids and no ids etc., so the only way to approach this is to try and filter out the children that are contained in the parents within the same collection.

Comment: The code processes HTML content that is input by users that is not standardized in any way.

Comment: As pointed out by Ηρακλής Β. your expected results includes '6' instead of 'd'.

Comment: Looks like you mean **top level divs** not "parents" - a parent is an element that has a child.

Comment: If you want top-level (_3, _6) then you're better off filtering to those first `$("body>div")` and then applying your regex to that set.  It'll be much quicker.

Comment: Thank you for pointing out @freedomn-m. I updated the question and the title for nmore clarity. I only need a collection where there are no elements that may be children of other elements. Thank you for the heads up.

Also, as stated the HTML is user input and the elements that the collection is created from are not in any particular order and contains all sorts of elements from within user input content.

The aim here is that the filtration of the DOM collection will eliminate redundant AJAX requests.

Comment: Got there in the end...

Answer (score 1):

How about just taking the top ones with the text in them?

Change `body` to another container if needed

```js
let $divs = $("body>div")
$divs = $divs.filter(function() {
  return $(this).text().indexOf("contains")!=-1
})

console.log($divs.length)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div class="div_1"> no key here </div>
<div class="div_2"> no key here </div>
<div class="div_3"> contains {key}
  <div class="div_a"> no key here </div>
  <div class="div_b"> contains {key} </div>
  <div class="div_c"> no key here </div>
  <div class="div_d"> contains {key}
    <div class="div_e"> contains {key} </div>
    <div class="div_f"> no key here </div>
    <div class="div_g"> contains {key} </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="div_4"> no key here </div>
<div class="div_5"> no key here </div>
<div class="div_6"> contains {key} </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that the answer to the title of the question is different from the answer you asked for in the end, as far as it concerns the collection you wanted ([".div_3", ".div_6"].

The parents in the snippet are [".div_3", ".div_d"] if I am not wrong. Please specify which set you want to get.

Comment: Yes, looks like a typo in the requirements.  Unfortunately, answers are for adding answers to the problem (which this does not).  When you have 50 rep, you can add comments to the question, which this should be.

Comment: Hey. no no type, only [".div_3", ".div_6"] are required. Because they contain all the {key}s .... so processing div_d is not needed because it will be processed as a part of div_3. I'll try and update the title :) thank you for the heads up !

Comment: Just updated the title ... had to make it alot longer for clarity's sake, but the actual question as always is in the body of the question and not in the title :)

Comment: But div_6 isn't a parent - there's no child elements of div_6

Comment: Thank you ... reworded that part of the question to eliminate any confusion:

-- Essentially, given collection_A create a collection_B that does not contain elements that may be children of other elements in the collection.

Answer (score 0):

> return those that don't have a parent that is also in the collection

Probably not very efficient, but you can check if each node is within the key collection by filtering the key collection to the node:

```
var divs = keydivs.filter(function() {
  return keydivs.filter($(this).parent()).length == 0;
});
```

Example:

```js
// Find all nodes across all available, OPs code to include top-level and child nodes here
var keydivs = $("div").filter(function() {
  return $(this).contents().first('[nodeType=3]').text().indexOf("{key}") >= 0
});
console.log(keydivs.length, keydivs.map(function() {
  return this.className;
}).get());


// filter those that don't have a parent that is also in the collection
var divs = keydivs.filter(function() {
  return keydivs.filter($(this).parent()).length == 0;
});
console.log(divs.length, divs.map(function() {
  return this.className;
}).get());
```

```css
div>div { margin-left: 1em; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="div_1"> no key here </div>
<div class="div_2"> no key here </div>
<div class="div_3"> contains {key}
  <div class="div_a"> no key here </div>
  <div class="div_b"> contains {key} </div>
  <div class="div_c"> no key here </div>
  <div class="div_d"> contains {key}
    <div class="div_e"> contains {key} </div>
    <div class="div_f"> no key here </div>
    <div class="div_g"> contains {key} </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="div_4"> no key here </div>
<div class="div_5"> no key here </div>
<div class="div_6"> contains {key} </div>
<div class="div_7"> no key here
  <div class="div_h"> no key here </div>
  <div class="div_i"> contains {key} </div>
  <div class="div_j"> no key here </div>
  <div class="div_k"> contains {key}
    <div class="div_l"> contains {key} </div>
    <div class="div_m"> no key here </div>
    <div class="div_n"> contains {key} </div>
  </div>
</div>
```